# Ordering field in creation form in Forest Admin

Tags: forestadmin

Is there any way ordering fields in creation form in Forest Admin ?
And hide useless fields ?

[image]

I don't find this information in documentation

**SOLUTION :**

I didn't see the ordering button

[image]

Forest Admin is a very good product BTW !! Congratulations

Answer (score 3):

The layout editor in Forest Admin is super powerful to hide/re-order fields and columns.

You can find all information in the doc right here: https://docs.forestadmin.com/documentation/reference-guide/views/using-the-layout-editor-mode/customize-your-creation-and-edition-forms